# react - $regex search for two separate keys in MongooseDB object, can only access one at a time

Tags: javascript, reactjs, regex, mongodb

```
const keyword = req.query.keyword
        ? {
                name: {
                    $regex: req.query.keyword,
                    $options: "i",
                },
          } && {
                category: {
                    $regex: req.query.keyword,
                    $options: "i",
                },
          }
        : {};

    const products = await Product.find({ ...keyword })
```

In my react app, I'm using a search bar component which makes DB queries based on a keyword (in the above example, 'category' and 'name' are both keys in a MongoDB model).  With the above, I can only access the second on the list, i.e. 'category'.  Bizarrely this worked fine with the above syntax until this morning, so I don't know what I've changed.  The only other file I've changed is .css so I doubt there's anything at fault there.

Is there a way to access both at once?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is you're using `&&` on objects which are truthy causing the second expression to be returned.

From the [Logical AND docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_AND),

> `expr1 && expr2`
>
> If `expr1` can be converted to `true`, returns `expr2`; else, returns `expr1`.

You should be using the [`$or`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/or/) operator to query on `name` or `category` fields.

```js
const keyword = req.query.keyword
  ? {
      $or: [
        {
          name: {
            $regex: req.query.keyword,
            $options: 'i',
          },
        },
        {
          category: {
            $regex: req.query.keyword,
            $options: 'i',
          },
        },
      ],
    }
  : {}
```